# What is the use of `schema` typedef in GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I'm getting started on GraphQL with Apollo + Express and I see that [the example](http://graphql.org/code/#apollo-server-https-www-apollographql-com-docs-apollo-server-github-https-github-com-apollographql-apollo-server-npm-https-www-npmjs-com-package-apollo-server-express) adds a `schema` name at the bottom of the typedefs:

```
let typeDefs = [`
type Query {
  hello: String
}

schema {
  query: Query
}`];
```

And after defining the resolvers it generates the schema with `makeExecutableSchema`:

```
let schema = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers});
```

However if I remove the `schema` part of the typedefs I can still use my endpoint normally, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:3000/graphql/?query={hello}
```

returns:

```
{"data":{"hello":"world"}}
```

But if I change the query part for something else, the server fails:

```
let typeDefs = [`
type Query {
  hello: String
}

schema {
  testquery: Query
}`];
```

> GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "testquery"

I have read through [Apollo's tutorial pages](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/example.html) and also the [How To GraphQL tutorial for Node.js + GraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/1-getting-started/) but can't find reference to that `schema` part.

What is it used for?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/three-ways-to-represent-your-graphql-schema-a41f4175100d/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**About the schema**

A schema can have up to three root operation types but it requires only one. The query type must be present in every schema and needs to be an object type ([Spec](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016/#sec-Initial-types)). This type is the root type when making queries to GraphQL. Furthermore there is a mutation root type that is used when making mutations. The latest addition is the subscription type.

**About root types**

Root types are simple object types. They can have fields and these fields are arguments. By default the query type is called `Query`, the mutation type is called `Mutation` and the subscription root type is called `Subscription`. If you follow these standard names the `schema` specification can be omitted.

```
# Doesn't need further specification, Query is the default name
type Query {
  # ...
}
```

Still you can name these types however you want. To define which of your object types is a root type to enter the graph you have to use the schema definition.

```
# Non standard query type name
type MyQuery {
  # ...
}

schema {
  # Needs to be defined in the schema declaration
  query: MyQuery
}
```

The same thing can be done for mutation and subscription types.